# How can I fix the rendundancy in my ER-Diagram?

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, erd

I've a problem with my ER-Diagram, I hope somebody can help. The scenario: users can create contacts. The user can also add notes to the contact. The note consists of one text field. The contacts can be connected to the notes, that means; one contact can be linked to several notes and one note can be linked to several contacts. Now I have an entity "User" and an entity "Contact", it's a many to many relationship. But I'm stucked at one point: I'm not sure if "Note" also have to be an entity, because I've to show the many to many relationship between the notes and contacts, but I've also to show the relation between the user and the note. This would lead[image: ER-Diagram] to a circle which is redundant. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to show `note` as an entity. Now, since you already defined a relationship between `contact` and `note` there is no need to show another relationship between `person` and `note`. You can get `note` for a `user` with `user` and `contact` combination.